# C, C++ preprocessor macro

Tags: c++, c

Can anyone please explain how this works

```
#define maxMacro(a,b) ( (a) > (b) ) ? (a) : (b) 

inline int maxInline(int a, int b)
{
  return a > b ? a : b;
}

int main()
{  
  int i = 1; j = 2, k = 0;
  k = maxMacro(i,j++); // now i = 1, j = 4 and k = 3, Why ?? Where is it incremented ?
  //reset values
  i = 1; j = 2, k = 0;
  k = maxInline(i,j++); // now i = 1, j = 3, and k = 2, Why ??
  return 0;
}
```

So, I want to know where exactly is the value of j incremented, while checking
   condition or while returning or while calling ?

- a. using macro
- b. using inline method

UPDATE :
Thanks to all, now I understand this. But just out of curiosity, why would anyone do j++ while calling method, why not increment j after calling method, this way it would be less confusing. I saw this piece of code somewhere so asking it !!

Comment: A good practice is indeed not to increment in the same instruction if it isn't necessary. Another good practice is never to call the max macro, to ban it forever.

Comment: As for that question afterwards, because it saves typing.

Comment: I believe readable, less confusing code is more important than less typing and confusing code. This will save time in future.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue is the preprocessor does just straight text substitution for macros.

```
maxMacro(i, j++)
```

becomes

```
( (i) > (j++) ) ? (i) : (j++)
```

As you can see, it does two increments when j is greater.

This is exactly why you should prefer inline functions over macros.

Comment: Agreed, see https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE31-C.+Never+invoke+an+unsafe+macro+with+arguments+containing+assignment%2C+increment%2C+decrement%2C+volatile+access%2C+or+function+call

Answer (score 10):

```
k = maxMacro(i,j++);
```

expands to:

```
k = ( (i) > (j++) ) ? (i) : (j++)
```

Because of the sequence point of `?:` the behaviour of this is well defined. When `i` is less than the initial value of `j`, `j` is incremented twice and k receives the once incremented value of `j`.

(If `i` were greater than the initial value of `j`, then `j` would be incremented only once when evaluating `(i) > (j++)`, `k` would be assigned that value of `(i)` and the second increment would not be performed.)

In:

```
k = maxInline(i,j++);
```

maxInline is called with the values `i` and `j` before increment (1 and 2), j is incremented *before* the function call, and `k` is assigned the return value of maxInline (2).

Answer (score 6):

Macro results in *textual* expansion. It happens before the compiler is even considering expressions and operators, and immediately after it had split the input text into individual tokens. Thus, the following line:

```
k = maxMacro(i,j++);
```

is *exactly* equivalent to the following line after macro expansion:

```
k = ( (i) > (j++) ) ? (i) : (j++);
```

Obviously, there are two increments here.

On the other hand, inline functions are just functions, and work exactly like non-inline ones for the purpose of the call. And in function calls, expressions in the argument list are evaluated first, and then their values are bound to respective parameter names inside the function body. Thus, the evaluation only happens once.

Answer (score 5):

This is why macro is evil!

A macro is literal text subsitution by the proprocessor before your compiler gets to it so `k = maxMacro(i,j++);` becomes `( (i) > (j++) ) ? (i) : (j++);`. I hope you see the problem here.

In the (inline) function call, the value of a and b is passed by value into the function where the initial value of i and j is passed in, after which j increment.

Comment: The behaviour is well defined, there's a sequence point in ?:

Comment: Is there? Oops. I've removed that bit then.

Answer (score 3):

Calling a macro is not the same as calling a function.
The preprocessor replaces the reference to maxMacro(i,j++)
with literal text that looks like this.

(i) > (j++) ? (i) : (j++)

A post increment operator uses the current value of its target,
and then increments its target.  So if i = 1 and j = 2, the following
happens:

(i) > (j++)   // 1 is compared to 2, and j is incremented to 3
? (i) : (j++)  2 is greater than 1, so the "b" value is passed
along.  j++ is invoked again, so the previous value 3 is returned
from the expression, but as a side effect, j is incremented to 4.

On the other hand, the inline function works just like a non
inline function as far as how the parameter variables are treated.
j++ is referenced once when it is put on the
stack as part of the function call.  The function call operates
with a b value of 2 and returns its result(2) while j is incremented
to 3 as a side effect.

Note:  your question indicates k=3 after the call to maxInline.  I got
k=2 after that call - the result I'd expect.

I hope this clarifies things . . .

K

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CERT C Coding standard:

[PRE00-C. Prefer inline or static functions to function-like macros](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE00-C.+Prefer+inline+or+static+functions+to+function-like+macros)

This is a great resource, lots of information about various little gotchas that one should avoid to make their code clean, stable, and secure :)

Answer (score 0):

Weird. So far nobody has mentioned that the inline function option is type-safe, where the macro isn't!

Comment: The macro is typesafe in that it will only work if there is an operator> defined on the two types in question, plus implicit conversions to a common result type.

Comment: But it doesn't enforce the same types on the two parameters. Use it with char* and int and you'll see what I mean.