# Prefix increment in C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, increment, prefix

Could somebody explain why b = 150 ?

```
#define CUBE(X) ((X) * (X) * (X))

using namespace std;

int main( void )
{
    int a = 3,b = 0;  

    cout << "before "<< endl;
    cout << "a = " << a;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "after"<< endl;
    b = CUBE( ++a );
    cout << "a = " << a;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C, C++ preprocessor macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263607/c-c-preprocessor-macro)

Comment: @BoPersson: Related, but not a duplicate... not least because that one doesn't feature UB through incrementing multiple times between sequence points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you're using a macro. Macros are not functions.

The line:

```
b = CUBE( ++a );
```

gets re-written as:

```
b = ((++a) * (++a) * (++a))
```

before your code compiles.

[The code then invokes Undefined Behaviour](http://www.ideone.com/P3U9P) because you increment `a` several times between sequence points.

It would be better if you used a function instead.

Comment: yes i know that inline functions are better, but i just need the answer to this question ;) i understand situation if i got b = CUBE( a++ );

Comment: @wolf3d: The situation is the same with `++a` as it is with `a++`. Any collection of operations that alter and read `a` between sequence points is undefined.

Comment: @wol3d: As Tomalak Geret'kal said with `a++` the behaviour is not defined. Maybe you understood what code the compiler has generated, but this does not mean that every compiler will do it the same, or that other versions of the same compiler will do the same.

Comment: Thank You for replay, read it all and I figured out the b's value on peace of paper :D

Comment: @wolf3d: How could you figure it out on a piece of paper?  There's no wrong answer here.  My compiler gives 216.

Comment: @wolf3d: Benjamin said "there's no wrong answer here" with respect to the various evaluations of the final result of `b`, whereas in fact every answer is wrong because the final result of `b` is undefined.

Comment: i misunderstood this statement... my english and c++ understanding isnt the best... sry

Comment: @wolf3d: No problem; I realised it was slightly unclear as I rewrote it.

Comment: @Tomalak: When I say "there's no wrong answer here", that means that any answer the compiler gives is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Benjamin: No it's not, because it's UB. Not sure how else to say it!

Comment: @Tomalak: So, you're saying that if the compiler gives an answer of 150 or 216, it's not acceptable?

Comment: @Benjamin: That's right. It's not acceptable. The code is broken, because it invokes UB. You should throw away the result, fix the code, and start again.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, obviously the code is not acceptable.  I'm not saying that the code is okay.  Obviously I'm talking about the compiler's behavior in response to the code.

Comment: @Benjamin: The compiler's behaviour _can be anything_. It is undefined. You may get a value of 150, or of 216, or of 999.. or your computer may explode, or a black hole may form in your armpit. Is that "acceptable"?

Comment: @Tomalak: "The compiler's behaviour can be anything".  That's exactly what I mean by "there is no wrong answer".

Answer (score 3):

`(++a) * (++a) * (++a)` is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Answer (score 3):

Undefined behaviour- you modify `a` more than once between sequence points. This is why `inline` functions are the vastly superior option.